# JQuery button multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code in my html file.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Guess" id="submit">
```

I have the following code in my javaScript file. Every time I click the (#submit) button I want the below code to execute.  The problem is that it executes the first time I click the button, but will not execute any time after that.  How can I make the below code execute every time the button is clicked without refreshing the page?  Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    user_Input = $('#text').val();
    history_Guess.push(user_Input);

    $('#chances').replaceWith('<p> You have '+ (max_Guess - history_Guess.length) + ' chances left!</p>');
    $('#hot_Cold').replaceWith('<p>'+status_Guess()+above_Below()+'</p>');

});
```

Posting complete code below if needed:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ben Levine | Guessing Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
        <h1>Ben Levine</h1>
        <h2>Guessing Game</h2>
    </header>

    <div>
      <section>
            <form>
            <p>Guess a number (1-100)</p>
            <input type="text" name="guess" id="text"><br>
                <div id="chances">
                    <p>You have 5 more chances</p>
                </div>
                <div id="hot_Cold">
                    <p>You are hot, but you need to guess higher</p>
                </div>
                <div id="direction">
                    <p>You are getting hotter/colder</p>
                </div>
                <div id="history">
                    <p>Previous Guesses: </p>
                </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Guess" id="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Hint" id="hint"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Reset Game" id="reset">
            </form>
      </section>

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2014 Ben Levine</p>
      </footer>

    </div>
    <script src="javaScript/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javaScript/application_2.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**javaScript:**

```
var random_Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
var user_Input = 0;
var max_Guess = 5;
var history_Guess = [];


$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    user_Input = $('#text').val();
    history_Guess.push(user_Input);

    $('#chances').replaceWith('<p> You have '+ (max_Guess - history_Guess.length) + ' chances left!</p>');
    $('#hot_Cold').replaceWith('<p>'+status_Guess()+above_Below()+'</p>');

});

function status_Guess(){
    if(random_Number===user_Input){
        return Win();
    }else if(Math.abs(random_Number - user_Input) < 10){
        return "You are very Hot!"
    }else if(Math.abs(random_Number - user_Input) < 25){
        return "You are Hot!"
    }else if (Math.abs(random_Number - user_Input) < 50){
        return "You are cold!"
    }else{
        return "You are very cold!"
    }

};


function repeat_Check(){
    for (var i = 0; i<history_Guess.length; i++){
        if (history_Guess[i]===user_Input){
            return "You already guessed this number"
        }
    }
};


function above_Below(){
    if (user_Input === random_Number){
        return " Wow you are amazing!"
    }else if (user_Input < random_Number){
        return " Guess Higher!"
    }else{
        return " Guess Lower"
    }
};


function check_Turn(){
    if (history_Guess.length > max_Guess){
        return "Game Over!!!"
    }
};


function validate_Input(){

    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;  

    if (user_Input.value.match(numbers)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};


function reset_Game(){
    new_Game();
};

function hotter_Colder(){
    if (history_Guess.length>0){
        if (Math.abs(random_Number - user_Input) < Math.abs(random_Number - history_Guess[history_Guess.length-1])){
            return "Getting hotter"
        }else{
            return "Getting colder"
        }
    }else{
        return "First Guess"
    }
};

function Hint(){
    return random_Number;
};


function Win(){
    alert("Congratulation, you won the game")
};

});
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These Elements

```
$('#chances').replaceWith('<p> You have '+ (max_Guess - history_Guess.length) + ' chances left!</p>');
$('#hot_Cold').replaceWith('<p>'+status_Guess()+above_Below()+'</p>');
```

no longer exist if you click the submit button again. Try this:

```
$(function(){
// your other code here
$('#submit').click(function(){
  history_Guess.push($('#text').val());
  $('#chances').replaceWith("<p id='chances'> You have "+ (max_Guess - history_Guess.length) + ' chances left!</p>');
  $('#hot_Cold').replaceWith("<p id='hot_Cold'>"+status_Guess()+above_Below()+'</p>');
  return false;
});
```

Really, I would not replace anything. Instead overwrite the contents of an HTML Element with `$(selcetor).html('code goes here');`.

```
$(function(){
// your other code here
$('#submit').click(function(){
  history_Guess.push($('#text').val());
  $('#chances>p').html('You have '+(max_Guess - history_Guess.length)+' chances left!');
  $('#hot_Cold>p').html(status_Guess()+above_Below());
  return false; // don't even use the event Object
});
```

Comment: Use `$(selector).text()` since you don't need to parse HTML.

Comment: Yes, that would work too. I just did that in case you want to add HTML in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#chances').replaceWith('<p> You have '+ (max_Guess - history_Guess.length) + ' chances left!</p>');

$('#hot_Cold').replaceWith('<p>'+status_Guess()+above_Below()+'</p>');
```

You are replacing your divs `chances` and `hot_Cold` so they won't exist the second time you click, change it to this to replace the contents of the divs:

```
$('#chances').html('<p> You have '+ (max_Guess - history_Guess.length) + ' chances left!</p>');

$('#hot_Cold').html('<p>'+status_Guess()+above_Below()+'</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault();` won't do anything because you don't pass `event` as a parameter.

Change:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
```

to:

```
$('#submit').click(function(event){
```

Comment: Hello, The event.preventDefault() stopped the page from refreshing after I clicked the (#submit) button despite not putting function(event).  But I added event like you suggested above, but still multiple clicks of the button won't keep rerunning the code.  I have to refresh the page in order to get the button click event to work.

Comment: then you need to post a complete code example so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: That only worked because `window.event` and `event` are the same thing. Pass that parameter anyways, for older IE, which don't support the `Event` Object. This is part of the answer. You can't replace the Elements you are getting by the jQuery `id` selector, when they have already been replaced.

Comment: Complete code posted above. This is my first attempt creating an interactive website, so apologizes for any terrible practices you stumble upon.